# R gridlines appear and disappear using GRID() function in plot

Tags: r

I have the following R code and am seeing odd behavior - when I run the plot command, the grid lines flash briefly in the graphics display (and look correct), but then vanish- almost as if some other layer (perhaps a background?) is getting written over them.  Is there some other aspect of my plot that I need to set?  The desired behavior is for the grid to persist on the display.

```
library(faraway)
data(pima)
plot(Species ~ Area, data=gala, grid(nx= NULL, ny = NULL, lty = 1, lwd = 1, col="gray60",     equilogs = TRUE))
```

oddly, if I change the ny parameter to "ny=nx"

```
plot(Species ~ Area, data=gala, grid(nx= NULL, ny = nx, lty = 1, lwd = 1, col="gray60", equilogs = TRUE))
```

as shown in the grid help page: http://127.0.0.1:31232/library/graphics/html/grid.html

I get the following errror
Error in grid(nx=NULL, ny = nx, lty = 1, lwd = 1, col = "gray60", equilogs = TRUE) : 
  object 'nx' not found

but the plot shows vertical gridlines (no horizontal).

R 2.12.0 (2010-10-15) running on XP SP3, if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used grid() before. but it seems to work if you just run the grid function after the plot function, since it adds a grid to an existing plot.

```
library(faraway)
data(pima)
plot(Species ~ Area, data=gala)
grid(nx= NULL, ny = NULL, lty = 1, lwd = 1, col="gray60",equilogs = TRUE)
```

Edit: To expand, grid is not an argument of plot, it takes an existing plot and sets a grid over it. In your earlier code you put a grid over your opened plot (since it gave a plot.new() error I assume you had a window open) and then erased the screen to plot the scatterplot.

Comment: Or explicitly supply as the `panel.first` argument

Comment: Being new to R, I was hopeful that putting the grid() specification inside the plot function would keep the gridlines behind the data - on a dense scatterplot it's distracting when the gridlines sit on top of the data.  For anyone else trying to address this problem, using a HSV specification with an alpha value seems to give the desired effect - eg grid(nx= NULL, ny = NULL, lty = 1, lwd = 1, col= hsv(h = 0, s = 0, v = .8980392, alpha = .8) ,equilogs = TRUE)

Comment: Another option would be to simply plot the points again after the gridlines: library(faraway);
data(pima);
plot(Species ~ Area, data=gala, type='n');
grid(nx= NULL, ny = NULL, lty = 1, lwd = 1, col="gray60",equilogs = TRUE);
points(Species ~ Area, data=gala)